# How can I get value of EditorFor in ASP.Net Mvc and passing value in a button as parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want pass some Id's values from my Edit form.
Let say I want pass value of ProductId, CountryId and ModelId and I tried like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return Update(@(model.ProductId),@(model.CountryId),@(model.ModelId) )/>
```

But not working.
I'am in my Edit form and this is my form.

```
@model Products.Models.Product

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Product</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CountryId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ModelId)


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Model, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Status, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return Update(@(model.ProductId),@(model.CountryId),@(model.ModelId) )/> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is your javascript `Update()` method? And why are you passing the original values of the model to it? And why are you not just submitting the form? You also need to show your POST method.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you for response, becouse I will have three buttons in the same form  with diferent functions, the one for Increase status, the second one for decrease status and the therd one for updating the hole table.... Is this possible to get those values I'am asking for?

Comment: You have not shown 3 buttons in your view. And none of that is explained in your question. And you have not responded to any of my queries. No one can possibly answer this.

Comment: @StephenMuecke , Jonas did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return Update(@Model.ProductId,@Model.CountryId,@Model.ModelId)/>`  And you will get all three Values. Happy coding!

Comment: Perfect, it's working. I don't how to thank you my dear! You just got  me without strange questions. Some poeple generate miljon questions that answers.